# Having bcrypt in gemfile is not allowing me to restart rails server and removing it is causing issue in browser (asking me to add it back)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have seen similar query being asked about issues with bcrypt but none of them discuss about this particular issue that I am facing currently. The solutions are either restarting rails server or installing bcrypt gem both of which are not helping me.
I am using Windows 7

Here are the problems I am facing,
1. If I have bcrypt 3.1.7 in my Gemfile, I am not able to start the rails server. The command 'rails server' gives me below error

```
C:\row\RailsInstaller\workspace\app2>rails s
C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw3
    2/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
    from C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1
    .7-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1
    .7-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.
    8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.
    8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.
```

2.  If I remove the bcrypt 3.1.7 in my Gemfile, then I am able to start the server but in browser I am seeing this error

```
LoadError in UsersController#show
cannot load such file -- bcrypt
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',   '3.2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt',   '3.1.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'byebug'
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.6.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    ansi (1.5.0)
    arel (6.0.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.7-x86-mingw32)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (3.5.1)
      columnize (~> 0.8)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2)
      slop (~> 3.6)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.3.0)
    ffi (1.9.6-x86-mingw32)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    globalid (0.3.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    guard (2.12.4)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (~> 2.7)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-minitest (2.3.1)
      guard (~> 2.0)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hitimes (1.2.2-x86-mingw32)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.2.8)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.2)
    listen (2.8.5)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    loofah (2.0.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    mini_backtrace (0.1.3)
      minitest (> 1.2.0)
      rails (>= 2.3.3)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.5.1)
    minitest-reporters (1.0.5)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    nenv (0.2.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    notiffany (0.0.6)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    pg (0.17.1-x86-mingw32)
    pry (0.10.1-x86-mingw32)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
      win32console (~> 1.3)
    rack (1.6.0)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activerecord (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.0)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.1)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ruby-progressbar (1.7.1)
    sass (3.4.13)
    sass-rails (5.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (2.12.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10-x86-mingw32)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (4.0.1)
      hitimes
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2015.1)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.0.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (~> 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    win32console (1.3.2-x86-mingw32)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt (= 3.1.7)
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.2.0.0)
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  guard-minitest (= 2.3.1)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  mini_backtrace (= 0.1.3)
  minitest-reporters (= 1.0.5)
  pg (= 0.17.1)
  rails (= 4.2.0)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring (= 1.1.3)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
```

I am not sure what to do now. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you please add your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to the question?  It is most likely that one of your other gems depends on bcrypt

Comment: @muttonlamb I have added Gemfile and Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1. Update your system's bcrypt to be current; this is independent of Rails.

```
$ gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'
```

Step 2. Verify bcrypt works by using IRB; this is independent of Rails.

```
$ irb
> gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.10'
=> true
```

Step 3. If Step 1 and 2 succeed, then update your Rails Gemfile:

```
gem bcrypt, '3.1.10'
```

Step 4. Bundle your gems so your Rails app gets its own copies of gems:

```
$ bundle install
```

Step 5. Start your server by using bundle:

```
$ bundle exec rails server
```

Do these steps succeed for you? If so, great.

If not, then can you please edit your question to show exactly which step didn't work, and copy/paste the exact error message?

Comment: I reverted all the changes that I did in that branch and I don't see any issue in the browser but I am still not able to start the server with this line in Gemfile     'gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7''
If I comment out the line, then I am able to start the server.
Also I updated my bcrypd, verified and did a bundle install. Still I am seeing this issue

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to make it more step-by-step. Can you please copy/paste whatever result you're seeing for whichever of the steps isn't working for you?

Comment: Great! It worked. So was it an bcrypt version issue?

Comment: Could be a version issue, or perhaps the new version correctly installed/reinstalled some of the native pieces, or the bundle set the path correctly. Glad it's working for you now!